# Why does local variable value still exist when control comes out of function

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *sample();
int main(void)
{
  int *p;
  p=sample();
  printf("%d",*p);
  return 0;
}

int *sample()
{
  int *p,x=10;
  p=&x;
  return p;
}
```

In the code above `x` is local variable. When I compiled above with gcc I'm getting output:

> 10

A local variable is only alive in the function where it is declared and as the control comes out of function local variable should be de-allocated. But this is not happening. 
wWy its printing 10? Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: You're  [stealing the hotel key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794)

Comment: For anyone who doesn't get the reference @Ingo made, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope which is also a great answer

Comment: Ah yes, that one. Still a fun analogy to read.

Answer (score 4):

While the behavior is officially undefined in the C standard, in practice values in memory stick around until something else overwrites them.

More details can be found at [Why do I have values in my array that I didn't assign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115578/why-do-i-have-values-in-my-array-that-i-didnt-assign/14115969#14115969)

Answer (score 2):

I modified your program just a little. See below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *sample();

void donothing ();

int main(void)
{
  int *p;
  p=sample();

  donothing();

  printf("in main(), *p = %d\n",*p);
  return 0;
}

int *sample()
{
  int *p,x=10;
  p=&x;

  return p;
}

void donothing ()
{
  int x[10], y;

  y = 17;
  return;
}
```

When I run it now, here's what I get ...

```
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$ ./stack 
in main(), *p = 17
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$
```

It is never safe to return the address of a local variable as that is typically established on the stack and can be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behavior. Returning reference of a local variable has unpredictable behavior and you were just unlucky that the value was still around.

Answer (score 0):

There's no garbage collection in C.

`x`,a local variable, cease to exist, when `sample` exits

Your case is an Undefined Behavior.